# How can one handle the debug and release versions of the web config file in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I know we can handle different versions of the web.config file (such as debug, staging and release) in asp.net web projects. How can we do the same in SharePoint projects by utilising this asp.net feature (bearing in mind that there might be more than one server in the farm, i.e. every server needs to be updated with the config settings)?

Answer (score 0):

You should register your web.config changes using the `SPWebConfigModification` class during the `FeatureActivated` event of a `FeatureReceiver`.  Here is an [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/archive/2009/01/21/web.config-modifications-with-a-sharepoint-feature.aspx) on how to use them.  Then you could have 3 xml files with your different configurations for Development/Stage/Production.  During your `FeatureActivated` event you could load the configuration for a particular environment based on the address of the current site.  For example, you would have a stage website called 'mysite.stage.com' and so the xml would be 'mysite.stage.com.xml'.

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
  base.FeatureActivated(properties);

  SPSite siteCollection = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;

  string host = 
    siteCollection.WebApplication.GetResponseUri(SPUrlZone.Default).Host;

  string fileName = String.Format("{0}.xml", host);

  // Read the xml and make web config modifications...
}
```